# How to manually change current date to post date in frontend?

Tags: php, date

Well I want to know how the viewer on my website can change the wordpress current date to the post date (preferable from the dropdown as Day and Month). So if today's wordpress date is 22 December, there must be some way to have dropdown for both days and months).

**Reason:**

Well I've worked on an PHP Code which displays a table values each day. Each values are differ from each day. With my designed code, they only able to view the current date values but not the whole year. Obviously my designed code takes the date of the Wordpress default. So I need a way I can also put the whole year dates in dropdown way so that If customer selects any date, it must change the wordpress time. With this,a viewer can check the values of whole year. I also want to load the page with the current date

Indication for this can also be fine

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to put date filter for user? so user can select day and month then that day and month post will load , Like this way you want?

Comment: Kinda yes, but not "Post", it must totally change the current time of the wordpress and must display future dates (e.g. 01, May, 2018)

Comment: sorry , I am not getting you..that actually you want when user select day and month..

Comment: yeah, when user select day and month (this is not a membership site, so I dont need to have any kind of logins/making account). When I say user, it means any viewer of the site.

Comment: yes but what should happen when user select day and month?

Comment: It must change the Current Wordpres (or built it PHP) default time

Comment: Suppose I want to display time under my website. It displays like this 22 september 2014. Now after this time, I want the filter input selection which displays all the days (from 1 to 31) and all months. If they select that date and month, it must display on the frontend. However, make sure that it is actually changing the whole wordpress.

Comment: Yes I got your point , but then do you want to display whole wordpress data of selected date?

Comment: I've a PHP code working on my website, it will gives the output of that date. It will fetch from the CSV  `if ($line_array['1']==date('j-M-y'))
{

echo '<table></table>'`

Comment: Any idea to change wordpress date by filter?

Comment: Sorry but I am confuse that what you want when user select day and month?

Comment: Ok, let's say when user select day and month, let wordpress load everything that is on that date.

Comment: Ok, so I'm very close for my answer. I notice that time is nothing to do with Wordpress in true sense. It's all fetch from PHP. So basically it is PHP time. Now the question arises, how to change PHP time automatically or by selecting from the SELECT OPTION

Comment: Please refer this for time and date in PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php